# Point R is inside the square forming an equilateral triangle ORL having one side equal in length to the side of the square. Find the Angle NRA.

Tags: geometry

The length of the diagonal of a square NOLA is 9√ inches. Point R is inside the square forming an equilateral triangle ORL having one side equal in length to the side of the square. Find the measure of the angle NRA

Can someone tell me the value of angle NRA? I tried divided 180 degrees by 3 since its an equilateral triangle but 60 degrees does not seem to conform with the properties of square since its angle needs to be 45 degrees when you bisect it.

Comment: partial diagram: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3896680/the-diagram-shows-an-equilateral-triangle-ade-inside-a-square-abcd-what-is

Comment: Thanks! I was able to solve it now